# copying and reversing arrays?

Tags: arrays, netbeans, reverse, copying

1.The two copies should be done in a single for loop.
2.The output should be made in a separate loop.The output should display 5 lines for each number on each one of the arrays as follows. “ARRAY1[index]= xx  ARRAY2[index] = XX ARRAY3[index] = XX” Array3 should contain the first arrays numbers but reversed (5-1).

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
 {
        // Constants Section
            final int FIVE = 5;                          
            final int ONE = 1;                          

            // Variable Declaration Section
            int[] firstArray = {1,2,3,4,5};             
            int[] secondArray;                                                          
            int[] finalArray;                                                       
            int i;                                       


// Variable Initialization Section
            secondArray = new int[FIVE];                
            finalArray = new int[FIVE];                 

// Code Section
              for (i = 0; i <FIVE; i++)       
            {  
                secondArray = firstArray;  
                finalArray = firstArray;
            }

            for (i = FIVE - 1; i >= 0; i--)   
            {

                System.out.println("Array1 = " + firstArray[i] + " Array2= " +   secondArray[i] + " Array3= " + finalArray [i]);
            }




   }
}
```

PLEASE HELP, IM A HIGH SCHOOL STUDENT WHO IS COMPLETELY CLUELESS ABOUT PROGRAMMING. (THE SIMPLER THE BETTER)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you need!

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
 {
        // Constants Section
            final int FIVE = 5;                          
            final int ONE = 1;                          

            // Variable Declaration Section
            int[] firstArray = {1,2,3,4,5};             
            int[] secondArray;                                                          
            int[] finalArray;                                                       
            int i;                                       


// Variable Initialization Section
            secondArray = new int[FIVE];                
            finalArray = new int[FIVE];                 

// Code Section
              for (i = 0; i <FIVE; i++)       
            {  
                secondArray[i] = firstArray[i];  
                finalArray[i] = firstArray[FIVE-i-1];
            }
//For Printing you can loose any logic. This would print in the reverse order but if you want your could change the loop
            for (i = FIVE - 1; i >= 0; i--)   
            {

                System.out.println("Array1 = " + firstArray[i] + " Array2= " +   secondArray[i] + " Array3= " + finalArray [i]);
            }




   }
}
```

I think this should do it, Correct me if i misunderstood..

Comment: Thank you so much! But how do I make firstArray print 1-5 and not 5-1?

Comment: Change the last for loop to for(i=0;i<FIVE;i++) and then see.